# How to embed React Components in html pages

Tags: reactjs

I want build a React component like

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return (<div>This is a simple component</div>);
    }
}
```

and use it like

```
<MyComponent></MyComponent>
```

in several different pages and even multiple times in a single html page.

I dont want to create a SPA just to enhance my web application's UI with React components.

Comment: `ReactDOM.render(
    <MyComponent />,
    document.getElementById('myID')
);` and in your html file have this `<div id="myID" />` So you have options, this can also be done in jQuery using the dialog component

Comment: are you using  reactjs along with react-router-dom ?

Comment: No I have just started learning React and I want somebody to help me search to the right way.

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.getElementById('id'));
```

You can render in your HTML like this:

```
<div id="id"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers but what I would like to know is if I can render it in my HTML like <MyComponent></MyComponent> and how.

Answer (score 3):

Simply adding React components into HTML code is not possible, because `<MyComponent></MyComponent>` is not HTML at all, it is [JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html).

#### Explaination

JSX is a special syntax that can be 'transpiled' to Javascript, so in essence `<MyComponent></MyComponent>` will end up beeing Javascript code, which obviously can not just be put into HTML code.

The Javascript code generated from JSX then will be executed and generates actual HTML code.

It **is possible** to add HTML tags into JSX, because HTML can be interpreted as JSX (and will be transpiled to Javascript as well), like:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return <div>
            <h2>HTML in JSX works</h2>
            <SomeOtherJsxComponent />
        </div>;
    }
}
```

But it is **not possible** to add JSX into HTML, like:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <JsxInHtmlDoesNotWork />
    </div>
</body>
```

React is Javascript, so everything that is necessary to add Javascript functionality to HTML also applies to adding React to HTML.

#### (nearest) Solution

So what you could do is to move your existing HTML into to some JSX wrapper (which is probably not what you would like to do, because this goes in the direction of creating a SPA, what you don't want), e.g.:

```
<html><head>
    <title>My web site</title>
</head><body>

<h1>Some HTML title</h1>
<p>Some HTML content.</p>

<!-- add a container, where you want to include react components -->
<div id="injected-react-content"></div>

<!-- import the react libraray -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>

<!-- setup react root component other components -->
<script type="text/babel">
    class RootComponent extends React.Component {
        render(){
            return <div>
                <MyComponent />
            </div>;
        }
    }

    class MyComponent extends React.Component {
        render(){
            return (<div>This is a simple component</div>);
        }
    }

    const domContainer = document.querySelector('#injected-react-content');
    ReactDOM.render( React.createElement(RootComponent), domContainer );
</script>

</body></html>
```

For some more background information on how to add React to an existing HTML website, see e.g.:

- [stackoverflow.com/questions/65917670/how-to-use-react-components-as-part-of-legacy-html-js-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65917670/how-to-use-react-components-as-part-of-legacy-html-js-app/65945804#65945804)
- [stackoverflow.com/questions/69607103/react-component-not-displayed-in-html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69607103/react-component-not-displayed-in-html/69620365#69620365)

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for is not possible right now with React, you want to use what is known as web components.

https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-create-your-own-html-elements-with-web-components--cms-21524

Read this to learn how to.

The other method is obviously

```
ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.getElementById('id'));
```

If you have to stick with React.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to stick with React so I would like to know if i use the method that you suggest, for every component that I am going to use (even the same multiple times) I have to call ReactDOM.render? What is the best practice for saving this Javascript code? I was thinking for every distinct html page to have a distinct  js file with the ReactDOM.render calls. The components are going to be saved seperately.

Comment: Yes, calling it everywhere is a fairly standard practice, if you are just starting to convert to React.
I can tell you the two ways, it's up to you to choose.
1) Render calls in same js file: Keeps code consolidated.
2) Render calls outside of the same js file: Everything follows export syntax, so much easier to use, when you move over totally to React JSX

Answer (score 2):

In index.jsx change the typical search for element root getElementById and change the logic to a getElementsByTagName scheme.

```
let elements=document.getElementsByTagName('MyComponent');
for (element of elements){
    ReactDOM.render( <MyComponent />, element );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of options which can be explored here

1. parcel bundle
   https://javascriptpros.com/creating-react-widgets-embedded-anywhere/
2. direflow bundle

https://jhinter.medium.com/using-react-based-web-components-in-wordpress-f0d4097aca38

Answer (score 0):

Best solution I found is to compile the React Component using build and then refer the static files into your solution just like any js or css normally. With this approach was it does not matter if its js/jsx/tsx also import and html tag all get converted and it works. No need for Babel or Webpack or even React dom reference as the chunks of builds contains of requried references. Yes u cannot refer the Component as  but if u provide a root div as entry point, it will have ur React Component as the browser understands it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).